# Extra }, or forgotten $. ... \z@ $\relax $ seqstrict}}{39}{figure.4.7} and so on

Tags: floats, captions, align

This time I have a strange problem. Following code is from the *.lof file:

```
\babel@toc {german}{}
\addvspace {10\p@ }
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1.1}{\ignorespaces Architektur des $\mathbb {K}$-Frameworks}}{3}{figure.1.1}
\addvspace {10\p@ }
\addvspace {10\p@ }
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {3.1}{\ignorespaces IMP-Modul}}{26}{figure.3.1}
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {3.2}{\ignorespaces Syntaxdefinitionen}}{26}{figure.3.2}
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {3.3}{\ignorespaces Endmodul}}{26}{figure.3.3}
\addvspace {10\p@ }
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {4.1}{\ignorespaces IMP-Konfiguration}}{31}{figure.4.1}
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {4.2}{\ignorespaces K-Regeln}}{33}{figure.4.2}
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {4.3}{\ignorespaces Beispielhafte Betrachtung eines Terms}}{34}{figure.4.3}
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {4.4}{\ignorespaces K-Konfigurationen in Backus-Naur-Form}}{35}{figure.4.4}
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {4.5}{\ignorespaces Regeln f\"ur $\relax $\@@underline {\hbox {\tmspace +\thinmuskip {.1667em}\tmspace +\thinmuskip {.1667em}\tmspace +\thinmuskip {.1667em}}}\mathsurround \z@ $\relax +\relax $\@@underline {\hbox {\tmspace +\thinmuskip {.1667em}\tmspace +\thinmuskip {.1667em}\tmspace +\thinmuskip {.1667em}}}\mathsurround \z@ $\relax $ strict}}{37}{figure.4.5}
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {4.6}{\ignorespaces Rechenklasse f\"ur en Ausdruck $x\tmspace +\thinmuskip {.1667em}*\tmspace +\thinmuskip {.1667em}(y\tmspace +\thinmuskip {.1667em}+\tmspace +\thinmuskip {.1667em}2)$}}{38}{figure.4.6}
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {4.7}{\ignorespaces Regeln f\"ur $\relax $\@@underline {\hbox {\tmspace +\thinmuskip {.1667em}\tmspace +\thinmuskip {.1667em}\tmspace +\thinmuskip {.1667em}}}\mathsurround \z@ $\relax <=\relax $\@@underline {\hbox {\tmspace +\thinmuskip {.1667em}\tmspace +\thinmuskip {.1667em}\tmspace +\thinmuskip {.1667em}}}\mathsurround \z@ $\relax $ seqstrict}}{39}{figure.4.7}
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {4.8}{\ignorespaces KResult und KResultLabel}}{39}{figure.4.8}
\addvspace {10\p@ }
\addvspace {10\p@ }
```

The lines with figure 4.5 and 4.7 are causing the errors:

```
Extra }, or forgotten $. ... \z@ $\relax $ seqstrict}}{39}{figure.4.7}
Extra }, or forgotten $. ...und \z@ $\relax $ strict}}{37}{figure.4.5}
```

I give you the problematic parts from my original tex file:

```
\begin{align}
&a_{1}<=a_{2}\rightleftharpoons a_{1}\curvearrowright \Box<=a_{2}\\
&r_{1}<=a_{2}\rightleftharpoons a_{2}\curvearrowright r_{1}<=\Box
\end{align}
\begingroup\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\captionof{figure}{Regeln für $\underline{\,\,\,}<=\underline{\,\,\,}$ seqstrict}
\vspace*{\baselineskip}\endgroup

\begin{align}
a_{1}\,+\,a_{2}\,\rightleftharpoons\,a_{1}\,\curvearrowright\,\Box\,+\,a_{2}\\
a_{1}\,+\,a_{2}\,\rightleftharpoons\,a_{2}\,\curvearrowright\,a_{1}\,+\,\Box
\end{align}
\begingroup\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\captionof{figure}{Regeln für $\underline{\,\,\,}+\underline{\,\,\,}$ strict}
\vspace*{\baselineskip}\endgroup
```

I don't see any mistakes there. Compiling works fine, i.e. PDF file is being generated and everything seems fine. But these errors are disturbing me. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Maybe the align environment is incompatible with the capt-of package, this might cause the problem. But the others sections are working fine. All other figures excluding 4.5 and 4.7 have the same structure, but no errors.

Help me guys!

Thanks

Comment: The `\underline`s  must be `\protect`ed: `\protect\underline`.

Comment: \protect isn't working. It is supposed to be an unknown command.

Comment: Ok, now it works. I have deleted the "$" from the caption and put the operators "+" and "<=" in the math mode: ...$+$... and ...$<=$... with the \protect command. Now everything works fine. Thanks!

Comment: @user2379123, you may add an answer yourself to not leave the question unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

The code works without problems on a recent LaTeX kernel (after May 2019), because several commands have been made robust.

I suggest defining `\blank` to stand for `\underline{\,\,\,}` and to use a proper `figure` environment.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\blank}{\underline{\mspace{9mu}}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\listoffigures

\mainmatter

\begin{figure}[htp]
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}

\begin{align}
&a_{1}<=a_{2}\rightleftharpoons a_{1}\curvearrowright \Box<=a_{2}\\
&r_{1}<=a_{2}\rightleftharpoons a_{2}\curvearrowright r_{1}<=\Box
\end{align}
\caption{Regeln für $\blank <= \blank$ seqstrict}

\begin{align}
a_{1}\,+\,a_{2}\,\rightleftharpoons\,a_{1}\,\curvearrowright\,\Box\,+\,a_{2}\\
a_{1}\,+\,a_{2}\,\rightleftharpoons\,a_{2}\,\curvearrowright\,a_{1}\,+\,\Box
\end{align}
\caption{Regeln für $\blank + \blank$ strict}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

For older LaTeX kernels, one can do

```
\newcommand{\blank}{\protect\underline{\mspace{9mu}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, the solution works fine. Before using the `\protect` command, I had to remove the `$`'s from the `\underline` command and put only the operators (`+` and `<=`) into the math mode.

Comment: There should be nothing wrong with \protect in `$\protect\underline{\,\,\,}+\protect\underline{\,\,\,}$. You would have to run latex twice to get rid of the error after adding \protect.